# Android Recycler (List) View Expansion Transition Animation

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-transitions

I am working on an android transition animation as shown in the attached gif below. At the beginning first 2 items of the list will be shown & when user click any of those item or swap it down we should show all the remaining items in that list.

As far I serach this can be archived using this [Android Transition Framework](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html) 
but I'm not sure whether its just transitioning between two activities or
transitions between transition between two activities along with shared elements transition (in this case Recycler view or list view)

Is there any one who can help me figure out the correct approach to archive this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is that you have shared elements, declare the items you need to take to the second activity as shared elements and take them to another activity.

And set a *slide* transition on the remaining list items and the bottom bar and set them on activity enter and activity exit transitions. That should do the trick.

I also want to point out that the shared elements will only work on post-lollipop versions, so this exact transition won't be achieved on older android versions using the transition backport in the support library. If you want to do this on the previous android versions, that is a bit too hard, this video can help you if you want this really badly on older android versions [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA](http://DevByte%20on%20custom%20animation%20between%20activities)